# Rails ajax update, no route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have an app with the models Game, Ownedsq, and User, and I am trying to update a square's :user_id within a game. I have been trying this for hours now, I believe the model relationships are correct and I am just missing something small so I appreciate any help.

Clicking on the update ownedsq button on a particular square gives me the error: **No route matches [POST] "/games/2"**, though I have    resources :ownedsqs in my routes.rb. My thought is maybe it isn't passing the correct ownedsq id, because I've never worked with the each_slice nesting before so maybe I messed that up.

**games/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="squareBoard">
    <% @ownedsqs.each_slice(10) do |slice| %>
        <div class='row'>
            <% slice.each do |s| %>
                <%= div_for s, class: 'sq' do %>
                    <%= s.boardposition %>
                    <%= button_to ownedsq_path(s.id), method: :put, type: 'JSON', data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, remote: :true %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**games_controller.rb**

```
def show
    require 'enumerator'
    @user = current_user
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @ownedsqs = Ownedsq.all
end
```

**ownedsqs_controller.rb**

```
def update
    @ownedsq = Ownedsq.find(params[:ownedsq_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        if @ownedsq.update_attributes(user_id: current_user.id)
            format.html {redirect_to game_path}
            format.json {head :no_content, status: :200}
        else
            format.html {redirect_to :back}
            format.json {status: :500 }
        end  
    end 
end
```

**game.rb**

```
has_many :ownedsqs
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

accepts_nested_attributes_for :ownedsqs

def after_create
    1.upto(100) do |i|
      Ownedsq.create("boardposition" => i)
    end
end
```

**ownedsq.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :game
```

**user.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :games
has_many :ownedsqs

accepts_nested_attributes_for :ownedsqs
```

**routes.rb**

```
 resources :games, :users, :ownedsqs
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set proper routes.

Add to `config/routes.rb` this line.

```
resources :games
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry I should've made it clearer I had that, I added the routes

Answer (score 0):

Two observations:

1. If you're using `params[:id]` in your *GamesController#show* action, shouldn't the line `format.html {redirect_to game_path}` in your *OwnedsqsController#update* action be more like:

   ```
   format.html { redirect_to game_path(@ownedsq.game) }
   ```
2. Are you sure the **game** with id 2 is present in your database? Otherwise the line `@game = Game.find(params[:id])` fails with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` which might trigger your route problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are calling update method and update method works with PUT request type you are calling it with POST request type

Answer (score 0):

if you type `rake routes` it will show you all the available routes,
`resources :games` will create routes with `PUT, GET, DELETE` methods, you won't have a route matching with `POST`. Your ajax call will make a post request.

For this to work for you, create a custom route like this

```
match '/games/:id', :to => 'games#create', :via => [:post]
```

or if you want it to go to update action, do this

```
match '/games/:id', :to => 'games#update', :via => [:post]
```